# При нажатии кнопки Next и Prev

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk

Шесть вопросов, при нажатии кнопки Next вопросы повторяются по кругу, а при нажатии кнопки Prev после первого вопроса вылетает ошибка. Нужно Next нажималась до шестого вопроса, а Prev нажималась до первого вопроса.

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";
    private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private Button mPrevButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;

    private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[] {
            new Question(R.string.question_australia, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_oceans, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_mideast, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_africa, false),
            new Question(R.string.question_americas, true),
            new Question(R.string.question_asia, true),
    };

    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
        }

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(true);
            }
        });

        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(false);
            }
        });

        mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });

        updateQuestion();

        mPrevButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
        mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });

        updateQuestion();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
    }

    private void updateQuestion() {
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }

    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswerTrue();

        int messageResId = 0;

        if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
        } else {
            messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Деление по модулю вычисляет остаток от деления. Оно не отсекает отрицательные значения, а для положительных делает "хождение по кругу", для заданных условий такое решение не подходит - замените проверкой на мин/макс:

```
    mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCurrentIndex >= mQuestionBank.length - 1) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Это последний вопрос!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            mCurrentIndex++;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

    updateQuestion();

    mPrevButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
    mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCurrentIndex <= 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Это первый вопрос!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            mCurrentIndex--;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
```